# xtemplate proposes 'objects,' but are they really objects? How can they be extended to become 'true' objects?

Tags: xtemplate

In chat, @cgnieder just pointed me to [`xtemplate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xtemplate) after poking around my own startup [`ltx3obj`](https://github.com/vermiculus/ltx3obj).
In section 3, the documentation states (at the time of writing):

> An *object type* (sometimes just "object") is an abstract idea of a document element that takes a fixed number of arguments corresponding to the information from the document author that it is representing.
>   A sectioning object, for example, might take three inputs:
>
> > "title", "short title", and "label".

But isn't this just a data structure at that point?
Wiktionary defines an object as an instance of a class, and it defines a class as

> A set of objects having the same behavior (but typically differing in state), or a template defining such a set.

Thus, objects have state *and* behavior, which I clearly put forward in `ltx3obj`.
I find it difficult to believe that `xtemplate` does not have a means of specifying behavior for a class (or object).
Unfortunately, I can't find any explicit support other than *templates*, which actually do the work of defining what an object *is* rather than just saying *it is*.
Moreover, templates do not (in a way that is immediately obvious) support methods.

So in conclusion, I have three *very* closely related questions:

- Is there a way `xtemplate` can be extended to include this?
- Does `xtemplate` already include this functionality, and is just non-obvious about it from the outside looking in?
- If not, are there any plans to officially include this functionality?

Comment: You seem to be thinking in object oriented terms for general programming: that's really not what `xtemplate` is about. Note that we (the team) feel that there are still big issues to solve with what `xtemplate` _is_ for.

Comment: I guess I'll try to answer if Frank doesn't (I'm no OO expert), but I wonder if this is a better fit for LaTeX-L

Comment: @JosephWright I hope to have some time in the coming weeks collecting some thoughts about this.  I suspect that it might make sense to mix LDB ideas with xtemplate and object-orientation, but I will need a bit of time.

Comment: Hey Sean, are there any news on that matter? Did you follow any team discussions? The question popped up as unanswered, but it is quite interesting.

Comment: @Johannes_B I was actually looking over this again browsing the LaTeX-L archives – no real resolution, but the `prototype` branch of the linked repo is actually coming together quite nicely :)

Comment: You could remove the `template` tag, it is not really suited. That will push it back on top and into the awareness of the team members around ;-)

Comment: Note: the team are having a physical meeting at TUG2015 and template-related stuff will be on the list of topics to talk about.

Comment: LaTeX-L conversation: http://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A2=latex-l;eac9f4d.1408